# Kubectl get status of pod as yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I can run `kubectl get pod nginx -o=jsonpath={'.status'}` to get just the status in json for my pod.

How can I do the same filtering but have the result returned in yaml instead of json?

So I would like to get this kind of output by the command:

```
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-05-31T14:58:57Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-05-31T14:59:02Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-05-31T14:58:57Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://5eb07d9c8c4de3b1ba454616ef7b258d9ce5548a46d4d5521a0ec5bc2d36b716
    image: nginx:1.15.12
    imageID: docker-pullable://nginx@sha256:1d0dfe527f801c596818da756e01fa0e7af4649b15edc3eb245e8da92c8381f8
    lastState: {}
    name: nginx
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2019-05-31T14:59:01Z"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with kubectl, there is no such output option for it.

However, it should be easy to extract that lines with `awk`.

```
kubectl get pods -o yaml | awk '/^status:/{flag=1}flag'
```

This starts the output at the line `status:`. In this case that is exactly what yo want.

Comment: Thanks, but that's now exactly what I meant, I updated my question. I guess though this is not possible with just `kubectl`, possible a manual conversion from json to yaml could work.

Comment: I misunderstood your question/output of `kubectl` a bit. I updated my answer.